# disable and enabling tooltip not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to turn off and turnon the bootstrap tooltip on toggle using jquery. but it doesnt seem to be working correctly. I am noticing once the bootstrap tooltip is turned off, its not turning back the tooltip to on again.
How do I  enable the tooltip back on ? appreciate your help

```
 .fa-3x {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.fa-lg {
  background-color: blue;
}
.toggle-button-on {
  color: green;
}
.toggle-button-off {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav li ").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
$(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
$(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
$(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
$(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
   // $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('disable') // Hide and destroy tooltips
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="" ng-Click="">
  <ul class="nav">
<li>
  <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange">toggle</i></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x">fa </i>
    <span>Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a ng-class="">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">fa </i>
    <span>Work </span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
    <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x">fa </i>
    <span>Scenario <br/>Music</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a ui-sref="faq"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
    <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x">fa </i> 
    <span>Faq</span> 
  </a>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is really confusing code, you should try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the documentation of toggleClass

```
<div class="tumble">Some text.</div>
```

Applying `.toggleClass( "bounce spin" )` to the same `<div>` alternates between `<div class="tumble bounce spin">` and  `<div class="tumble">`

So only use one `$(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-on");` and `$(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-off");`

Then it will work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion it didnt seem to work. Is it possible to show a working example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to re-initialize a disabled tooltip. This isn't working because the tooltip was already initialized. You need to enable it:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
```

Alternatively, rather than disabling the tooltip using:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
```

You could instead `destroy` the tooltip, and then re-initialize it like you were initially trying to do:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('destroy');
```

```
$(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
  $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
  $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
$(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
  $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
  $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('destroy');
});
```

Updated Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav li ").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
    $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
    $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
    $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
    $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('destroy');
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="" ng-Click="">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange">toggle</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x">fa </i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">fa </i>
        <span>Work </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x">fa </i>
        <span>Scenario <br/>Music</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="faq" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Default tooltip">
        <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x">fa </i> 
        <span>Faq</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable it in `toggle-button-on` event handler:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
```

**See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5g2zrwq/)**

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `toggle-button-off` event you are disabling the tooltip with `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');`

Then inside your `toggle-button-on` event you just need to enable it with `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');`

[enable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-enable)

Otherwise your code seems to work well.
Here is the working **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxbg3qyn/1/)**